# An algebraic extension of degree 3

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field and let $Z=\frac{X^3}{X+1} \in K(X)$.

Show that $K(X)$ is an algebraic extension of degree 3 of $K(Z)$.

I am trying to figure out first why $Z\in K(X)$ as I don't know that the field  K(X) contains the inverse of $(X+1)$. I only know that it contains X so it contains $X^{-1}$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $K(X)$ is the field of fractions of $k[x]$ i.e. is the field of 'rational' functions with coefficients in $K$ so $\exists (X+1)^{-1}$

Comment: Thank you vrey much.